# autofilter to exclude dates with "or" operator coming up with incomplete result

Tags: excel, vba

```
    Sub DOBdateRange()

    Dim Bfordate As Date
    Dim Afterdate As Date

    Bfordate = Worksheets("error").Range("i5").Value
    Afterdate = Worksheets("error").Range("j5").Value

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
   'çhange data formate to Date
    Worksheets("data").Select
    Worksheets("data").Range("a2", Range("a" & Rows.count).End(xlUp)).Offset(, 3).Select
    Selection.Name = "DOB"
    Selection.NumberFormat = "d/mm/yyyy"

   'filter and copy how many records match (exclude) date criteria,
    Worksheets("Data").Select
    Range("bq1").Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToLeft)).Select
    Selection.AutoFilter
    ActiveSheet.Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).AutoFilter _
                **Field:=4, _
                Criteria1:="<" & Bfordate, _
                Operator:=xlOr, _
                Criteria2:=">" & Afterdate** 

     Range("a1").Select
     Range("bq1").Select
     Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
     Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToLeft)).Select
     Selection.Copy Set NewSheet = Sheets.Add(After:=Worksheets("error"))
     Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone,     SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
    On Error GoTo duplicatesheet3
    NewSheet.Name = "DOBdateRange"
    On Error GoTo 0
    NewSheet.Range("A1").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Worksheets("dobdaterange").Range("d:d").Select
    Selection.NumberFormat = "d/mm/yyyy"
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Worksheets("dobdaterange").Range("a1").Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).EntireColumn.AutoFit
    With ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Borders
        .LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .Weight = xlThin
        .ColorIndex = xlAutomatic
    End With

    Worksheets("Data").Select
    Worksheets("Data").Range("A1").Select
    Selection.AutoFilter             'Remove auto filter

    Sheets("DOBdateRange").Select

    Exit Sub
```

Previously I was using range. Value to refer to date criteria since it wasn't working I thought its not picking up date format so I declared the dates as date, still its not filtering all the data, its generating incomplete result, after much searching and trying different things i decided to post it for direction. any help pointing to right direction will be highly appreciated. Thank you

Comment: are you working with dates ? cause they can be tricky. Try to define `Bfordate As Double` and `Afterdate As Double`. Also, you should get rid of the `Select` and `Selection` you have

Comment: @ShaiRado, yes I am working with date and did try lots of tricks and finally got it right by using your suggestion. life saver once again.. thanks a lot. Cheers! while stepping through and mapping it on local window it showed the date in some funny format so i did got doubt but it did exactly what i was looking for.